# JSON schema- Timestamp validation

Tags: json, validation, jsonschema

I am trying to create a Json schema regex to have a timestamp validation in milliseconds. Eg.20140508172846.127.
I tried like this Pattern:^[0-9] it's not working. please suggest any other way to perform timestamp validation.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a regex. The problem is the pattern you provided does not match floating point numbers.

You could try with:

```
(\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)\s+(\S+)
```

But you would need to specify exactly which timestamps values are allowed (and you will find for sure an answer in stackoverflow)